# How does "do something OR DIE()" work in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, conditional-statements

I'm writing a php app to access a MySQL database, and on a tutorial, it says something of the form

```
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("could not connect");
```

How does PHP know that the function failed so that it runs the die part? I guess I'm asking how the "or" part of it works. I don't think I've seen it before.

Comment: As an aside, don't use this kind of logic in actual applications. It still amazes me how many tutorials do that.

Comment: Why not use it? It is really nice and readable...

Comment: Is might be simple and appropriate for a tutorial, but you do not want your script to die ungracefully with an error message like that in front of real users. Showing a custom error page (without specifying the actual error!) + logging the error is a must.

Comment: You might still be able to use this technique to do that, though.

Comment: not really... killing the script doesn't leave you much to go on

Comment: I'm talking about the "or", not the "die".

Comment: mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or PrintNiceError('DatabsaeConnectionError');

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If the first statement returns `true`, then the entire statement must be `true` therefore the second part is never executed.

For example:

```
$x = 5;
true or $x++;
echo $x;  // 5

false or $x++;
echo $x; // 6
```

Therefore, if your query is unsuccessful, it will evaluate the `die()` statement and end the script.

Comment: Good explanation.
This "implied if" language construct of PHP is a little dangerous, because you can have statements that you think get executed but really don't, and that's not as obvious as if you had an if block.

Comment: This is called short-circuit evaluation and is useful in languages other than PHP as well.

Comment: By the way, you can only use a single statement after OR. A block statement will fail syntax checking (e.g. actual error message could be Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in ...)

Comment: And here I was, thinking this was some kind of advanced feature like python's `with` statement, when it's actually just a boolean expression... I think extra care should be taken when using this expression if you're expected to perform a cleanup in case of errors. Please, correct me if I'm wrong, but if you do `func_call($file) or die();` and the function fails, then the file is left open when the scripts dies.

Comment: @Petruza Is it even good practice to use `or` in situations where an `if` could work?

Comment: @BrassApparatus Now, looking at my comment 5 years later, I would say the  _or shortcut_ is not so bad after all, it's simple, concise and elegant.  
But the danger of taking for granted than rightmost expressions will get evaluated when they might not still holds. (I would say a good practice is never using as an expression something that produces a side effect, like _++_) 
In every situation that an _or shortcut_ works, a classic _if_ would work too.  
What I would advise against every time is using _die()_, one should handle error conditions gracefully.

Comment: Similarly works `AND` operator, but in this case second operator will never executed if the first returns `FALSE`

Answer (score 39):

PHP's **`or`** works like C's **`||`** (which incidentally is also supported by PHP - **`or`** just looks nicer and has different operator precedence - see [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)).

It's known as a [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator because it will skip any evaluations once it has enough information to decide the final value.

In your example, if `mysql_connect()` returns TRUE, then PHP already knows that the whole statement will evaluate to TRUE no matter what `die()` evalutes to, and hence `die()` isn't evaluated.

If `mysql_connect()` returns FALSE, PHP doesn't know whether the whole statement will evaluate to TRUE or FALSE so it goes on and tries to evalute `die()` - ending the script in the process.

It's just a nice trick that takes advantage of the way **`or`** works.

Comment: +1 for naming short circuiting.  Might also have named "side effect".  We are not interested at all in the die() return code, we just want the effect of its execution.  (It is not always going to be die()). This is not always popular with the purists as some effects can be obscure.

Comment: and this isnt all. you can also use and to combine stuff, where you want that one thing definitely works before doing a second thing.

Answer (score 14):

It works as others have described.

In PHP, do not use "die", as it does NOT raise an exception (as it does in Perl). Instead throw an exception properly in the normal way.

die cannot be caught in PHP, and does not log - instead it prints the message ungracefully and immediately quits the script without telling anybody anything or giving you any opportunity to record the event, retry etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add more code if the connection doesn't work, beyond a die statement:

```
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass)
if(!$con)
{
     // ... add extra error handling code here
     die("could not connect");
}
else
{
     echo "Connected";
}
```