# Strange behavior of the OR DIE() construct with PHP class

Tags: php, oop, die

I've read carefully the reply to this question [How does “do something OR DIE()” work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432454/how-does-do-something-or-die-work-in-php) but yet I can not use the `OR DIE()` properly into my script using oop like in the following snippet of code

```
class UsingMysql {
    ...
    function QueryDB ($query_string) {
         $resource = mysql_query ($query_string);
         return $resource;
     }
}
...

$mysql = new UsingMysql();
...
function get_director() {
    global $mysql;
    $query_d = ...
    $result_d = $mysql->QueryDB($query_d) or die (mysql_error());
}
...
get_director();
```

My script works fine only when I remove the `OR DIE` construct from the statement. Why?

Comment: If your "do something" returns a falsey result, then the "or die()" will be executed as well; if your "do something" returns a truthy result, then the "or die()" will not be executed

Comment: @Mark Baker, I'm using `SELECT` in the query for MySQL, is the string returned considered like a logical value?

Comment: Any value can generally be tested for truthiness (e.g. integer or float 0/0.0 is false): in your case, a mysql_query will return false if the query execution fails/errors