# Unusual use of && operator

Tags: php, operators

I am trying to understand the below code but I am confused by the use of the `&&` operator.
Please explain the purpose of the `&&` operation in the following code

```
function getErrors($autoClean=TRUE) {
     $retVal = $this->getErrorMessages();
     $autoClean && $this->unsetErrorMessages();
     return $retVal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works............

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here, `&&` acts as a short-circuit operator as told by @robby.

- If you call getErrors(), $autoclean will be true, $this->unsetErrorMessages() will be
  executed.
- If you call getErrors(false), $autoclean will be false, $this->unsetErrorMessages() will not be
  executed.

The line provides us a behaviour to prevent default execution of any code
and also provides us facility to reduce lines of code
as

```
$autoClean && $this->unsetErrorMessages();
```

will be equivalent to

```
if($autoClean){
   $this->unsetErrorMessages();
}
```

Comment: @robby that's what I told, See the answer, I mentioned your name too. I just explained it, so that amber doesn't confuse with `if` in future.

Comment: Something it might be good to note: The if statement will probably be seen as cleaner code and more easily understood, even though it is 3x as many lines. Less lines aren't always better.

Comment: true @kevin , but some times optimization is needed like when you develop framework or something

Comment: @AshwaniShukla fair enough, I'm mostly used to compiled languages. At the very least a comment would be helpful for people not familiar with the language's idioms.

Comment: @AshwaniShukla This case has *nothing* to do with optimization, it's obfuscation at best (and most likely common folly).

Comment: @AshwaniShukla you can barely optimize PHP code anyways since PHP optimizes so much in the background by itself.

Comment: Code optimization is a set of methods of code modification to improve code quality and efficiency. A program may be optimized so that it becomes of a smaller size, consumes less memory, executes more rapidly, or performs fewer input/output operations. And it has nothing to do with the language(PHP), what matters for optimization is the way you write your code.

Comment: I doubt most compilers will make a difference between the two statements, and I seriously doubt a difference, is any, will result in a perceivable improvement in speed. Either way, I think second-guessing the compiler (or interpreter, ftm) is not a good idea for trivial matters.

Answer (score 30):

Here, `&&` acts as a [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator (see also the code example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)).

- If `$autoClean` evaluates to **`true`**, `$this->unsetErrorMessages()` **will** be executed.
- If `$autoClean` evaluates to **`false`**, `$this->unsetErrorMessages()` **will not** be executed.

Using `||` instead of `&&` would reverse this behavior.

The same behavior can obviously also be achieved by adding an additional `if` statement. In doing so:

- `a && b()` can be rewritten as

  ```
  if (a) {
      b();
  }
  ```
- `a || b()` can be rewritten as

  ```
  if (!a) {
      b();
  }
  ```

While the use of short-circuit operators can reduce the number of lines, it can also make code harder to read.

<s>In terms of execution speed, there should be no noticeable difference.</s>

---

**Update**

I have to retract my earlier statement about there being no noticeable difference in execution speed. Given the following two test scripts, i.e. a version with the short-circuit operator:

```
<?php
    $a = true;                                                                                                   

    function b() { global $a; $a = !$a; }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
        $a && b();
    }
?>
```

And a version with an `if` statement:

```
<?php
    $a = true;                                                                                                   

    function b() { global $a; $a = !$a; }

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
        if($a) { b(); }
    }
?>
```

It turns out that the second version (with the `if` statement) is **roughly 40% faster** (~450ms vs. ~750ms) on my PHP 5.5.9 version running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit).

Results may vary for different PHP versions and operating systems, but at least on my machine I consistently notice a significant difference in execution speed.

Comment: You can also use the literal word `or` and `and`  e.g `if ((true or true) and true)`

Comment: Basically its working on the principle of short-circuiting.In case of OR(cnd1 || cnd2), if cnd1 == true, it will short circuit the operation and never goes for cnd2. Similarly, for AND it checks cnd2 only if cnd1 is true.

Comment: Something it might be good to note: an equivalent if statement will probably be seen as cleaner code and more easily understood, even though it is 3x as many lines. Less lines aren't always better.

Comment: Great answer. _amber_, this is also the explanation behind the `someStatement() or die();` pattern [you may see elsewhere in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/432454/1426891).

Comment: Just to note from an internals perspective, the first one needs an implicit boolean cast [on the second operand] and an AND operation, which isn't needed when just doing `if ($a) { … }`, which is making the first code slower.